# Convert from diferent data types from struct to unsigned char array as return value

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I am trying to convert from struct members bytes to an unsigned char array as a return value from a function inside the same struct. Is there any way of storing all the struct's members in one char array and returning them when calling the struct?

My main problem is knowing the way of converting from shorts and ints to bytes stored in char array's index positions

Example as follows:

```cpp
struct protocol_header{
    unsigned char start_bytes[2] = {START_BYTE_1, START_BYTE_2};
    unsigned short protocol_version = PROTOCOL_VERSION;
    unsigned short flags;
    unsigned short error;
    unsigned int message_type;
    unsigned int regarding;
    unsigned char reserved[6];
    unsigned char inmediate_data_length;
    unsigned char inmediate_data[6];
    unsigned int bytes_remaining;
    void getHeader(unsigned char *data[44]){
      *data[0] = start_bytes[0];
      *data[1] = start_bytes[1];
      *data[2] = // now i do not know how to allocate the values from short to char bytes
    }
  };
```

**SOLUTION 1:**
It is not much, but it is an honest work

```
 struct protocol_header{
    unsigned char start_bytes[2] = {START_BYTE_1, START_BYTE_2};
    unsigned short protocol_version = PROTOCOL_VERSION;
    unsigned short flags;
    unsigned short error;
    unsigned int message_type;
    unsigned int regarding;
    unsigned char reserved[6];
    unsigned char checksum_type;
    unsigned char inmediate_data_length;
    unsigned char inmediate_data[6];
    unsigned int bytes_remaining;
    void getHeader(unsigned char data[44]){
      memcpy(&data[0], &start_bytes, 2);
      memcpy(&data[2], &protocol_version, 2);
      memcpy(&data[4], &flags, sizeof (short));
      memcpy(&data[6], &error, sizeof (short));
      memcpy(&data[8], &message_type, sizeof(int));
      memcpy(&data[12], &regarding, sizeof (int));
      memcpy(&data[16], &reserved, 6);
      memcpy(&data[22], &checksum_type, sizeof (char));
      memcpy(&data[23], &inmediate_data_length, sizeof (char));
      memcpy(&data[24], &inmediate_data, sizeof (inmediate_data));
      memcpy(&data[28], 0, 12); // bytes que no se usan pero relleno a 0
      memcpy(&data[40], &bytes_remaining, sizeof (bytes_remaining));
    }
  } header;
```

with this solution I am not solving the endian bits problems (I think) but for checking the code and output data it get's the goal

Comment: You can use `memcpy` to copy data from one location to another, irrespective of the source and destination data types. Maybe `memcpy(&(*data[2]), &protocol_version, sizeof(short));` (or something similar). On another note: **beware of structure padding**.

Comment: This code isn't valid C so don't use the C tag.

Comment: `unsigned char *data[44]` is an array of pointers. I guess, this is not what you want.

Comment: okay, no. My goal is getting an array of bytes with all the data from the members inside the struct

Comment: There's also an issue you might need your code to be able to handle: byte order of fields longer than one byte. Network byte order is usually used in network protocols (Big Endian). Intel machines and others use the Little Endian byte order for reading from and writing to memory multi-byte fields. If you encounter strange values with the simple memcpy() approach, the reason could be a mismatch in the byte order.

Comment: @rpress that's correct, you should use htons() and the like on every *ints* and *shorts* if the bytes are to be exchanged among machines with unknown endianness. I wonder whether a *reflectable* class would come in handy in this case.

Comment: I do not have experience in working with endianess but, how would work that reflectable class? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Adrian's comment, you can use `memcpy` to copy the whole structure, no need to go element by element.

```cpp
#include <string.h> // for memcpy()
#include <cstddef>  // for offsetof()

#include <iostream>

struct protocol_header {
    unsigned char start_bytes[2];
    unsigned short protocol_version;
    unsigned short flags;
    unsigned short error;
    unsigned int message_type;
    unsigned int regarding;
    unsigned char reserved[6];
    unsigned char inmediate_data_length;
    unsigned char inmediate_data[6];
    unsigned int bytes_remaining;
    void getHeader(unsigned char *data) {
      memcpy(data, start_bytes, sizeof(protocol_header));
    }
  // this is for gcc, other compilers have different syntax (e.g. #pragma)
  } __attribute__ ((packed));

// Remember that ph_data type will be a pointer type
typedef unsigned char ph_data[sizeof(protocol_header)];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  protocol_header ph;
  ph_data buffer;

  ph.regarding = 100; // Give something to read

  // populate the buffer
  ph.getHeader(buffer);

  // retrieve a member from the serialized object
  int regarding = *(int*)(buffer + offsetof(protocol_header, regarding));
  std::cout << regarding << std::endl;
}
```

You can leave the `packed` attribute out if you don't mind having padding bytes in the `char` array.